# Where to begin studying Biology in earnest, with preferably free sources?

Tags: mammals, book-recommendation

I am a biology enthusiast and would like to study Biology in earnest. I have basic knowledge of biology (high school level) and some extended knowledge of small animals, mainly about mammals as I am naturally interested in them.

So I would like to start studying veterinary and Mammalogy first.
I would prefer free sources for studying since I have little money available.

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E. I would recommend to have a quick look at the  tour (https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour), learn about Biology S.E and earn your first badge.

Comment: Okey Johhny will do now. EDIT: Got it :)

Comment: I think if you can [narrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biology#Branches) down your areas of interest a lot more, answering the question will be easier, other wise this question is too broad. (I have found that non-specialised, general  biology sites meant for open learning are not great, lack precision.) Narrowing down your areas of interest to something like Evolution, Genetics (if you are into mammals, may be Zoology, or if their behaviour, ethology) will get you good answers(recommendations).

Comment: Thank you for response what I am interest in Veterinary itself but for now I will start with Mammalogy I guess :)

Comment: Coursera may have some stuff you can use. https://www.coursera.org/learn/becoming-a-veterinarian/lecture/rS68J/teaching-learning-veterinary-medicine You can buy old mammology and vetinary  textbooks, you will likely find some free pdfs of them if you look in the right places. You may need to study up on college level biology first however. .

Comment: [Khan Academy > Biology][https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology] is very good. It offers a good broad introduction to the main fields of biology. It does not talk about mammalogy or veterinary though.

Comment: @Remi.b I have found some factual errors at places on Khanacedemy videos especially ones made by Sal Khan (talking about biology videos). So I think grabbing a book is better than learning from these videos.

Comment: I have modified your question. You want free stuff. Open source means (more or less) that the code or original material is not protected by copyright and can be modified and redistributed.  You are not interested in this.

Comment: Considering books, I guess the Campbell is the best place to start in biology, but it's really a general biology book and it's not focused on mammalogy, even if there are some chapters dedicated to animal physiology and animal diversity... you can probably find it in a library if you don't want to buy it, and there exists a pdf version as well. I hope it helps somehow. :)

Answer (score 1):

Before getting into veterinary and mammalogy, you might want to start with the basics. As many people have mentioned, **Campbell and Reece** is one of the best textbooks to start a foundation in biology. If you live near a public library you might find a 6th or 7th edition to borrow. Amazon has a few 7th editions for cheap as well. Although it is an introductory biology book, it will give you a wonderful tour of cellular and molecular biology that will make it much easier when studying animal physiology (which they also covered in the later chapters to a limited extent).

**Free Biology Text Books:**

**[Boundless Biology:](https://www.boundless.com/biology/)** Boundless is a company that has many free textbooks for high school level biology to help teachers in have a free online textbook.

I have also found a list of free biology text books [here](http://Hello%20SirGangALot,%20Before%20getting%20into%20veterinary%20and%20mammalogy,%20you%20might%20want%20to%20start%20with%20the%20basics.%20As%20many%20people%20have%20mentioned,%20Campbell%20and%20Reece%20is%20one%20of%20the%20best%20textbooks%20to%20start%20a%20foundation%20in%20biology.%20If%20you%20live%20near%20a%20public%20library%20you%20might%20find%20a%206th%20or%207th%20edition%20to%20borrow.%20Amazon%20has%20a%20few%207th%20editions%20for%20cheap%20as%20well.%20Though%20it%20is%20a%20basic%20biology%20book,%20it%20will%20give%20you%20a%20tour%20of%20cellular%20and%20molecular%20biology%20that%20will%20make%20it%20much%20easier%20when%20studying%20animal%20physiology%20(which%20they%20also%20cover%20in%20the%20later%20chapters).%20%20Free%20Text%20Books:%20Boundless%20Biology:%20Boundless%20is%20a%20company%20that%20has%20many%20free%20textbooks%20for%20high%20school%20level%20biology%20to%20help%20teachers%20in%20have%20a%20free%20online%20textbook.%20%20Coursera:%20A%20few%20people%20have%20already%20mentioned%20Coursera,%20which%20is%20a%20Massive%20Open%20Online%20Content%20(MOOC).%20Here,%20you%20can%20find%20many%20courses%20across%20a%20wide%20range%20of%20biology%20topics%20(and%20others!).%20You%20can%20enroll%20in%20a%20course%20(for%20free)%20and%20many%20times%20they%20come%20with%20accompanying%20free%20textbooks%20as%20well%20(at%20least%20that%20is%20what%20I%20have%20experienced).%20edX:%20Another%20MOOC%20that%20was%20started%20by%20Harvard.%20Khan%20Academy:%20Another%20great%20website%20for%20explanations%20of%20certain%20aspects%20of%20biology.%20As%20Tyto%20alba%20stated,%20there%20are%20some%20errors%20in%20the%20videos.%20I%20have%20also%20found%20a%20list%20of%20biology%20text%20books%20here%20that%20might%20be%20of%20use.) that might be of use.

**Free Mammology Textbook:**

As part of a National Science Foundation Grant, the Northwest Center for Sustainable Resources created ***[*Introduction to Mammology*](http://learnforests.org/sites/default/files/IntroductiontoMammalogy.pdf)***. It is a free textbook that was developed for a two-year Wildlife Technology program. It also contains information related to the lab portion of the program, but you can skip those and focus on the material.

**Free Online Coursework:**

**[Coursera:](https://www.coursera.org/learn/becoming-a-veterinarian/lecture/rS68J/teaching-learning-veterinary-medicine)** A few people have already mentioned Coursera, which is a Massive Open Online Content (MOOC). Here, you can find many courses across a wide range of biology topics (and others!). You can enroll in a course (for free) and many times they come with accompanying free textbooks as well (at least that is what I have experienced).

**[edX:](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-biology-secret-life-mitx-7-00x-6)** Another MOOC that was started by Harvard.

**[Khan Academy:](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology)** Another great website for explanations of certain aspects of biology. As Tyto alba stated, there are some errors in the videos.